# Livestreaming and PA: how to generate the 2 mixes?

Tags: mixing

Our church is looking into providing live streams of our services. Until now we've only provided audio recordings, which we produced by recording the main outputs of the PA mixer 1:1. 
This doesn't sound great, so I want to provide a better mix for the live stream.

I can see 2 basic approaches:

1. create a second mix on our mixing console (a Behringer X32). I can set up a pair of busses for the livestream, which allows me to use different fader settings for the livestream. This brings the volumes of speech and worship closer together. I can also add some reverb to get rid of the 'dry' sound of the PA mix, and mix in our audience mix to provide some ambience.
2. I see some people running a DAW to provide the mix for the livestream. This would give more flexibility (unlike solution 1, I can create separate EQ, compression and effects for each channel in the livestream). But it'd require a second sound engineer to run this mix.

Is there something I'm overlooking, any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely go with 1 if your mixing console has the functionality - option 2 adds unnecessary complication.